# инициализация свойств класса через конструктор из массива

Tags: php, dto

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты инициализации свойств класса, через конструктор из массива ?

Чтобы конструктору передал массива: `array("prop1" => "val1", ...)` и чтобы соответствующим свойствам класса установились заданные значения ?

Answer (score 0):

Замените функцию на конструктор в [Источнике](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336747/php-set-object-properties-dynamically)

```
<?php 

 function set(array $array) {
$refl = new ReflectionClass($this);

foreach ($array as $propertyToSet => $value) {
$property = $refl->getProperty($propertyToSet);

if ($property instanceof ReflectionProperty) {
  $property->setValue($this, $value);
 }
 }
 }

 $a = new A();

$a->set(
array(
'a' => 'foo', 
'b' => 'bar'
 )
);

 var_dump($a);
```

Comment: Сделал так:

  `  public function __construct(array $parameters = null) {
        if($parameters) {
            foreach (get_class_vars(static::class) as $property => $defValue) {
                if (!isset($parameters[$property]) || empty($parameters[$property]))
                    throw new Exception();
                $this->{$property} = $parameters[$property];
            }
        }
    }`

пойдет? или через рефлексию лучше?

Comment: На ваше усмотрение. Через рефлексию можно получить приватные и защищённые поля, через get_class_vars вряд ли..